# Request for retagging tinc-related questions

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

There are [6 questions related to Tinc VPN](https://serverfault.com/search?q=tinc+is%3Aquestion) at SF now. Would mass re-tagging them be of any use? I can do it manually, but 2k+ users may do it without the hassle of waiting for approval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been completed and all questions relating to Tinc VPN are correctly tagged.

<sup>Just providing an answer so this can be considered answered.</sup>